# Why is it giving me the cors error when fetching tha data from mongodb atlas data Api

Tags: reactjs, mongodb-atlas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of954.png)It's giving me the cors error when fetching tha data from mongodb atlas data api. it works fine with Postman and  Thunderclient

Comment: Please add an error snippet instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is enforcing CORS here. Basically the people who own the server set a header that says only these origins are allowed to read the data returned. The browser is the one that enforces this rule, and when using Postman or Thunderclient, theres no browser, so you're able to read it just fine.

One way to get around this is using a cors-proxy, take a look at something like https://corsproxy.github.io/ as an example

Comment: cors error is removed but now its giving me the new error.  i added the picture of error

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` mostly comes when the server stops. Check whether your previous request crashes your server or any other exception is raised.

Comment: This proxy only supports get requests and you're trying to do a post, thats most likely why